# Gatling - have certain percent of users do specific flow

Tags: scala-gatling

Is it possible in Gatling to have a scenario where 20% of users would do certain actions, 10% of users some other action, and 70% of users another different set of actions?

I thought that `randomSwitch` does that, but I think it is not doing that.
It is the probability you can specify that some chain will execute, it is not the percentage of users doing some specific chain.